# Windows 7 Aero decorations blinking every second

Tags: windows-7, hp-elitebook

After returning from lunch, my Citrix Receiver timed out, and the active window border, its shadow, and selected text started blinking every second. This also undoes dragging the window and closes open menus.

This also happened yesterday. I've scanned the system with Trend Micro Housecall (found nothing), searched for hours, and installed every Windows update. What's going on? Is the HP Bios update to blame?

I'm using an HP 850 EliteBook on a HP 2013 UltraSlim Docking Station. Undocking doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that removing the USB thumbdrive did the trick. I suspect HP's USB drive access manager is to blame. 6434 Windows log entries like this last one logged continuously since 9 AM with 0-6 second spacing seems to confirm:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        flcdlock
Date:          24-4-2015 12:43:19
Event ID:      105
Task Category: Service
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      CeesTimmerman
Description:
Device Locking Policy Refreshed.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="flcdlock" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">105</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>1</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-04-24T10:43:19.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>53926</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>CeesTimmerman</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```